# Android GridView load items vertically

Tags: android, gridview

Is it possible to load items in GridView with vertical orientation? I mean...

Normal situation - 3 columns

[image]

```
-----------------------------             
1      |  2      |    3
-----------------------------
4      |  5      |    6
```

[image]

Desired situation  - 3 columns

```
-----------------------------              
1      |  3      |    5
-----------------------------
2      |  4      |    6
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's upto my knowledge, I dont think you can change the cell alignment. be default, it is vertically aligned. however, i would like to know if there's any advancements. Also, if you could tell the problem or why you particularly want the cells to be aligned vertically, we might give some alternative.

Comment: This is a petition of my customer. He want to show some names in this order, vertically. I only want to show two columns, but to explain my problem i used 3 columns in my question. Thanks

Comment: @jzafrilla Got any solution for GridView load items vertically?

Comment: @Subra hi! Like Sahil Mahajan says, i dont think you can change this. Finally, i made my own view; LinearLayout horizontal that contains n LinearLayouts vertical and adding views to vertical layout. I'll share my code here.

Comment: How are you recycling your views like ListView/GridView?

Comment: @Soham thnx, we want Row 1|2|3 become Colum

Comment: yes but a) are you scrolling normally (vertically) or are you scrolling horizontally? b) in case you are scrolling normally (vertically) what do you want to show when you scroll down, what will the new row be? (that is the answer i have given)

Comment: just wanted to comment, what a good question. well presented too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible at all.

**Reason** ::

- There is technical glitch doing this since we want to scroll items vertically. And also the rendering items on the screen is also vertical direction. In this case we can not complete the calculation we need to do in the onLayout and onMeasure Method of the GridView.
- If try another way i.e some of us has suggested that snuffle the datasource as [1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8, ...]  but in this case what would be shuffle algorithm?
- When user flings vertically then how can you calculate how many items we need to render vertically and when to switch to next column to render the other items. there is no such mathematical formula for it.

I did some work on this and came to this conclusion.Hope this make unanswered question answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GridLayoutManager with RecyclerView, easy way to fill vertically data first is :

```
GridLayoutManager lLayout_artist = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),3,GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

You can change orientation of GridLayoutManager as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify, say you have a Grid like this

```
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9
```

now if you scroll it down vertically, it should basically be like this??

```
2  5  8
3  6  9
4  7  10
```

In this case,

- items 4 and 7 are not recycled, in fact they are moved to a new position
- item 1 is to be recycled
- only item 10 is introduced

Clearly, this is not how a normal ListView/GridView works where a row is recycled at a time, AFAIK you will need to customise GridView to get this functionality.

Comment: No its not the case. He wants Vertical GridView. i.e. Row becomes Columns.

Comment: Yes, but if its vertical, if its scrolls vertically. Otherwise it is a Horizontal GridView. Can you please clarify if its a vertical gridview or a horizontal one?

Comment: @Soham you are asking this right?http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/grid-lists.html ?

Comment: Nope, just trying to understand how this works. So if you take the example in the question and scroll down by one row, can you tell me the contents of the new row?

Comment: @Soham Sorry little confused!, if it is Portrait or Landscape scroll="horizontal" ,(like 2nd image in question) new row depend on the screen resolution (Ex:4 images or data Rows in Phones, 8 Rows in tabs)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to change the sequence of data?
In your example, change data to [1,3,5,2,4,6, ...] for horizontal orientation, [1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8, ...] for vertical orientation.

Answer (score 0):

// Have you ever used GridLayout [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html), Try this one:

```
File -> Import -> <sdk_folder>\extras\android\support\v7\gridlayout>
```

// Add this project as **library project**

// xml file - **activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    tools:context="com.example.gridlayoutdemo.MainActivity" >

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

// Java code

**MainActivity.class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private GridLayout gridLayout;
    private TextView[] textViews;
    private int noOfItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
        gridLayout.setOrientation(1);
        gridLayout.setColumnCount(3);
        gridLayout.setRowCount(3);

        textViews = new TextView[8];

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            textViews[i] = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            textViews[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            textViews[i].setText(String.valueOf(i));
            textViews[i].setTextSize(25);
            textViews[i].setPadding(50, 25, 10, 25);
            gridLayout.addView(textViews[i]);
        }

        setContentView(gridLayout);

        for (noOfItems = 0; noOfItems < 8; noOfItems++) {
            textViews[noOfItems].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                int pos = noOfItems;

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), pos + " Clicked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

// If you want to display horizontally than do this **gridLayout.setOrientation(0);**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout . and set child gravity to `Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL`

they even have `vertical` or `horizontal` orientation

Answer (score 0):

I Know the Question is bit old.. but i didn't find any Relevant answer so i Created one algorithm.

in Below code `crossAxisCount` is Nothing but a How many Grids aligned Horizontally i.e., in the above picture in portrait view we have '2' grids and in landscape we have '4' grids.
`arrayLength` means Total number of grids we have to provide to get that layout.

```
  final int crossAxisCount = 2;
  final int arrayLength = 8;
  final List<int> output = [];
  
  
  
  var runiCheck = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < (arrayLength/ crossAxisCount).ceil(); i++) {
    var runjCheck = -1;
    for(var j = i; j <= arrayLength; j+= (arrayLength / crossAxisCount).ceil()){
      runiCheck++;
       if((arrayLength % crossAxisCount != 0)){
         if(arrayLength < runiCheck) break;
           runjCheck++; 
        if(arrayLength % crossAxisCount < runjCheck){
          j--;         
        }            
      }else{
         runjCheck++;   
         if(runjCheck >= crossAxisCount) break;        
       }     
      output.add(j);    
    }    

  }
  print(output);
```

output:

```
[
0, 4,
1, 5, 
2, 6, 
3, 7
]
```

if we Change `crossAxisCount` to `4` and `arrayLength` to `21`(just a random numbers.)

```
  final int crossAxisCount = 4;
  final int arrayLength = 21;
  final List<int> output = [];
```

The output will be:

```
[
0, 6, 11, 16, 
1, 7, 12, 17, 
2, 8, 13, 18, 
3, 9, 14, 19, 
4, 10, 15, 20, 
5
]
```

I Know Using This Algorithm in very long lists/ arrays are bit expensive. but this is the Exact Solution.

I am new to Stack overflow please up vote my answer to get Motivated.

Answer (score -1):

You can Achieve this by using **GridLayout** instead of GridView.

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:rowCount="2">
</GridLayout>
```