# How to make a Custom view & repeat for multiple time in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I want to make a customs layout.

In that it contain one **Text View** and one **share button** at the bottom 
like this
[image]

I want to repeat this view for a multiple time like this

[image]

it should dynamically add view when new entrees is added to the db.
So can any one help me to solve this problem

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [grid view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html). That will help solve your requirement.

Comment: I used it but i stuck with this Issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580573/android-gridview-load-items-vertically.I want to scroll it horizontally.